# HTML editor for blog

Tags: html, mysql, plugins, editor

Sorry for asking such a dumb question. But I am not actually getting the name by which I should search this. I need a plugin for blog writing using which user can edit fonts and add image/s. While submitting, the generated html code can be entered into mysql. Can anybody help on this issue...

Comment: try: wordpress - google it

Comment: Sir, I know we are not google. That's why I asked you what term I used to search for plugin.. besides wordpress..

Comment: you didn't mention wordpress at all

Answer (score 1):

there are a bunch of text editors for weblogs, but I really like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). I think your issue has two sides. In the first place you should provide a text editor for users to enter their stuffs. In the second place you should have a server side approach to get what your users entered in order to save in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try CKEditor. You can download it from http://ckeditor.com/download